Angular Route Reuse Strategy Parent Route and Child Route
I want to create a custom RouteReuseStrategy. The purpose of this RouteReuseStrategy is to store the parent route when navigating from a parent to a child route.
Routes:
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [ dashboardAuthGuard ],
        children: [
            {
                path: "app",
                providers: [ ModalService ],
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "sale",
                        loadChildren: () => import("./dashboard/suffapps/sale/sale.module").then(module => module.SaleModule)
                    },
                    {
                        path: "reports",
                        loadChildren: () => import("./dashboard/suffapps/reports/reports.module").then(module => module.ReportsModule)
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: "login",
        loadComponent: () => import("./login/login.component").then(component => component.LoginComponent)
    }
];

Routing modules in app routes:
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: SuffappComponent,
    canActivate: [ saleActivateGuard ],
    canDeactivate: [ suffappDeactivateGuard, saleDeactivateGuard ],
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: SuffappSaleComponent,
        resolve: {
          resolver: saleResolver
        }
      },
      {
        path: "case",
        component: SuffappSaleCaseComponent,
        canActivate: [ caseActivateGuard ],
        resolve: {
          resolver: saleCaseResolver
        }
      }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class SaleRoutingModule { }

When going from /app/sale route to /app/sale/case route, I want to store /app/sale route.
I've read documentation and watched videos about RouteReuseStrategies but I don't know how to do it.
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle, RouteReuseStrategy } from "@angular/router";

export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  stored: { route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle } | null = null

  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log("shouldDetach", route.data["reuse"]);
    return route.data["reuse"]
  }

  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle | null): void {
    console.log("store", route, handle);
    this.stored = { route, handle: handle! }
  }

  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log("shouldAttach", this.stored?.route.routeConfig == route.routeConfig);
    return this.stored?.route.routeConfig == route.routeConfig;
  }

  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle | null {
    console.log("retrieve",  this.stored?.handle || null);
    return this.stored?.handle || null;
  }

  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log("shouldReuseRoute", future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig);
    
    return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
  }
}

I write this code.
This code stores the /app/sale route when going from /app/sale to /app/sale/case.
But there is a problem:
It also stores when going from /app/sale to /app/reports.
